# How to add bootstrap progress component during the api call to servlet

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, servlets, progress-bar

I want to show the Bootstrap's progress bar while invoking ajax api call to the servlet.

Please find the below code for my api invocation.

```
open(id) {
ajax({
url: 'api/get_order',
method: 'GET',
data: {
id: id
}
}, (data) => {
if (data.error == null) {
} else {
alert(data.error);
}
});
}
```

During the above ajax api call, i want to show Bootstrap's progress bar. Please find the below code.

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-
valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can increase/decrease the progress by changing the css on progress bar-

```
//on progress
$('.progress-bar').attr('style', 'width: ' + progress_status + '%;');
```

to calculate the value of progress_status:

1. if you want an actual progress bar that shows the status as on the server you will need support from server and calculate value based on response from server.
2. if you want a 'static' progress bar you can implement a loop/timeout and increase the progress_status based on some logic, e.g. increase by 10% in 2 seconds.